# POWER BI - Count unique values with condition

Tags: powerbi

I have a simple task  that cannot be solved. In the below table I want to Count number of As and Bs per unique Number. The code I have for A is

```
CountA =
IF (
    ISBLANK (
        CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Sheet1 (2)'[Number] ), 'Sheet1 (2)'[Cat] = "A" )
    ),
    0,
    1
)
```

But it does count A for Nunber 5 three times and the result should be 1.

```
Number  Cat
1        A
2   
3   
3   
4   
5        A
5        A
5        A
6   
7        B
8        B
8        B
8        B
```

Comment: "Count number of As and Bs per unique Number" - the number of A's for 5 is 3.  Please clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what your desired result is... Assuming that you want something like this:

[image]

Use these formulas:

```
Count A = CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table[Cat] ), Table[Cat] = "A" ) + 0

Count B = CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table[Cat] ), Table[Cat] = "B" ) + 0
```

where 'Table' is the name of your table.